# Getting error while creating controller in Asp.net Mvc with tdk

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my `sintak controller` on `asp.net mvc`,

```
 using Toyota.Common.Web.Platform;
 using FAMS.Models;

 namespace FAMS.Controllers 
 {
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
 }
```

**And have error:**

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Toyota' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   e:\ExampleApplication\ExampleApplication\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml    1   8   ExampleApplication

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely because you are missing a reference to Toyota. Right click on References and add that reference mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Toyota` reference which is you referred from your own `class Library` or dll.

1. If that project/dll is having any issue. referred project will not load the dll properly in this solution. So you may get an error (as you got).
2. As per the `@Khaltazar` answer you may missed the reference to add. You have referred the `NameSpace` as `using Toyota.Common.Web.Platform;` in your controller. But add the `reference dll` in to your `current project references`.
3. Finally `Clean` the solution and `Build / ReBuild`.
4. Stop the process if the `referred dll is being process` with any other (It may be `Locked`).